# How to flatten a 3D array where the 3d dimension is not fixed size into 1D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D array where each (x,y) cell contains a vector of strings (for simplicity) of different size.

What's the most efficient way to flatten this data structure into 1D array, i.e. creating a function mapping injectively each string to {1,...,n} where n is the total number of strings in the data structure.

Comment: Your title says 3D but you only mention 2D in the body. Which is it? Or is it a more general question about multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @AdrianMole apparently, the misterious third dimension is a vector in every cell of the table.

Comment: @bipll Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: Record the cumulative sum of the lengths of the strings in a 2D array of the same size. Position of string i, j, k is cs[i][j]+k. Going the other way, do a binary search and subtract off the left bound

Comment: @MadPhysicist Care to provide an example? I'm not quite sure I get it.

Comment: I'm not a C++ guy, but I could do C or pseudocode (or python) example. Would that work?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes pseudocode would be great! Thank you

Comment: Ok. Enjoy. Let me know if I can improve my pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map an index `i, j, k` to linear position `p` in O(1) and back in O(log N), where `N` is the size of the 2D array, not the total number of strings.

First, let's treat your 2D array as a 1D, since that just makes things much easier. Index `i` is the index of a vector in the array. Index `k` is the position of a string in the vector. `N` is the size of the array.

You can create an array of integers (e.g. `size_t`) that holds the zero-based cumulative sum of all the vector lengths:

```
lengths = array[N]
lengths[0] = 0
for(i = 1 to N)
    lengths[i] = lengths[i - 1] + size(array[i - 1])
```

If you want, you can compute the total number of strings as `total = lengths[N - 1] + size(array[N - 1])`.

Now, for a given string at index `i, k`, the position in the expanded array is just

```
p = lengths[i] + k
```

Given a position `p`, you map it to `i, k` using a bisection algorithm (binary search that returns the index of the left bound when an exact match isn't found):

```
i = bisect(lengths, p)
k = p - lengths[i]
```

Bisection is a simplified binary search, so O(log N).

All this works very nicely until you start expanding your vectors. At that point, insertion and deletion become O(N) operations, since you need to increment or decrement all the cumulative sums past the insertion point. To insert:

```
array[i][k].push(a_string)
for(z = i + 1 to N)
    lengths[z]++
```

And to delete:

```
array[i][k].pop()
for(z = i + 1 to N)
    lengths[z]--
```

By the way, if you still want to use indices `x, y` for the array, you can convert between the linear index `i` of `lengths` and back using

```
i = x + C * y
x = i % C
y = i / C
```

Here, `C` is the number of columns in your array. You can easily generalize this to any number of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't simple direct way work for you?

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
        std::vector<std::string> omg[3][4];
        std::vector<std::string> rv;
        for(auto const &row: omg) {
                for(auto const &cell: row) {
                        for(auto const &str: cell) {
                                rv.push_back(str);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer my question as I want to be able to map every cell in the 1D array to the corresponding cell in the 3D array and vice versa.

Comment: Oh, you want to have the inverse mapping? Cool, then you'll need to encode vector sizes/boundaries in your 1D array, or in strings thereof. Otherwise, you need to refine _different size_, say, postulate that the size of a vector is always computed by a deterministic function of its position in the table.